# Kendo UI Grid Sorting for Just One Column

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I just want one column in my grid to be sortable. I was thinking I could make the grid set to `sortable: false` and put `sortable: true` on my one column, but no dice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the grid to `sortable: true` and put `sortable:false` on all the other columns other than the one you want enabled as sortable. Sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/latenightcoder/HPBGY/1/).

Comment: how can we control sorting for just 2 columns? Or can we know how many maximum columns can we do the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

The following are steps you need to do:

**Step1:** 
Inside grid add the following property

```
sortable: {
    mode: "single",
    allowUnsort: false
}
```

**Step2:** 
which column you want to make sortable, set that column will be

```
sortable:true
```

and remaining column will be

```
sortable:false
```